# Delete data with checkboxes in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Im selecting multiple rows with checkboxes, and then i delete them with ajax with the code below. (it works fine..)

```
    <?php
include_once("../../files/connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['val']))
{
    $p = &$_POST['val'];
    foreach($p as &$v)
    {
        $v = "'". mysqli_escape_string($kapcs, $v) ."'";
    }
    $values = '('.implode(',',$p).')';
    mysqli_query($kapcs, "DELETE FROM kereses WHERE kereses_id IN $values") or die(mysqli_error($kapcs));

    echo 'Selected rows deleted.';
}
else
{
    exit("No rows selected with checkbox.");
}
?>
```

How can i put this code into that? I want to delete the images or files also from a folder, not just only the record from the sql table. Can someone help me?

```
$DestinationDirectory = "../../images/news/";
    if(file_exists($DestinationDirectory.$data['hir_thumb']))
    {
        unlink($DestinationDirectory . $data['hir_thumb']); 
    }
    if(file_exists($DestinationDirectory.$data['hir_big']))
    {
        unlink($DestinationDirectory . $data['hir_big']);   
    }
```

Comment: How are the image paths related to the IDs you're deleting from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can understand your question. 
Code does not checked, but try to adapt it to your enviroment.

```
<?php
include_once("../../files/connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['val']))
{
$p = &$_POST['val'];


foreach($p as &$v)
{
    $v = "'". mysqli_escape_string($kapcs, $v) ."'";
//select all the row

        $sor = $kapcs->query("SELECT * FROM kereses WHERE kereses_value = {$v}");

//fetch the row
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_row($sor)){

            //delete selected rows
            $delete = $kapcs->query("DELETE FROM kereses WHERE id= {$data['id']}");

            // if delete success
            if ($delete) {

                $DestinationDirectory = "../../images/news/";
                echo 'Selected row deleted from database.';
                    // unlink the thumbnail if exists
                                if(file_exists($DestinationDirectory.$data['hir_thumb']))
                                {
                                    unlink($DestinationDirectory . $data['hir_thumb']); 
                                    echo 'Selected thumbnail deleted from filesystem.';
                                }
                    //unlink the big picture if exists
                                if(file_exists($DestinationDirectory.$data['hir_big']))
                                {
                                    unlink($DestinationDirectory . $data['hir_big']);   
                                    echo 'Selected picture deleted from filesystem.';
                                }
            }


    }
 }


}
else
{
 exit("No rows selected with checkbox.");
}
?>
```

I hope that helps.